# Why Jmeter opens with a Console(command prompt) in background?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jmeter

I've searched through internet and couldn't find an explanation for this question, So posting in SO for a better understanding.

When i open **`Jmeter.bat`** the it opens **jmeter GUI** along with a **DOS window** in background. What is the need for this window?

If this window is to check the initial start-up errors, why is it still open after the GUI loaded.

Why shouldn't we use **`ApacheJmeter.jar`** instead of **`jmeter.bat`** for opening jmeter?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jmeterw.cmd which calls javaw under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter.bat sets some environment variables and then runs `java.exe -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`

Because it's calling java.exe and not javaw.exe, a command window also opens. Change the code to set JM_LAUNCH to javaw.exe to avoid the window.

Comment: Changing to javaw.exe just allows me to close the cmd.exe window and keep the Jmeter window open, How to make cmd.exe close automatically.

Comment: Javaw.exe shouldn't be opening a cmd window _at all_. The w in javaw stands for window. But I suppose if it's the only cmd window open, you can add the line `taskkill /im cmd.exe` to the end of jmeter.bat.

Comment: Upon further investigation, a better solution would just be to use jmeterw.cmd instead.